# In PWA, how to get files directly on app after sharing through share_target menu on mobile?

Tags: javascript, frontend, progressive-web-apps, file-sharing

My app registered as PWA and installing as expected, but when I choose them in share menu in android, it's open 405 nginx page (method POST not allowed) instead of app.

I don't want to send any data or requests to the server. There are any way to get files from share_target only in local app?

Here is my `manifest.json` share_target part

```json
  "share_target": {
    "action": "/",
    "method": "POST",
    "enctype": "multipart/form-data",
    "params": {
      "files": [
        {
          "name": "file",
          "accept": "*/*"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Added this to worker, but this listener didn't call anyway. Only show nginx error.

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  const request = (event as FetchEvent).request;
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  if (request.method === 'POST') {
    console.log('event', request);
  }
});
```